# Loop within a loop logic

Tags: c, visual-studio, cs50

I am veeery new to coding. Could you explain the logic behind the loop within a loop code in C. To be more precise:

I do not get in my code the sequence of how the loops happen.

I.e if I type in the code size: 1 only one # will appear, even though there are two 'for' loops, so should not each of them print out # separately so two hashtags overall?

i.e when I type 2 the terminal gives four hashtags, which I get. Because from my logic each for loop creates two hashtags (once when each integer equals 0 and the second one when the integer get added ++ and equals 1 (where it stops)

i.e when I type 3 the terminal gives 9 hashtags, which I do not get again, because in my mind each for loop should have give us 3 hashtags so 6 in total (integer =0 then 1 then 2)

So again, my question is how does the sequence happen here? If you could please explain one of the examples I gave I think I would get the rest.

Sorry for the long post, hopefully my question is clear.

Code:

```
int main(void)
{
    int n;
    do
    {
        n = get_int("Size: ");
    }
    while (n < 1);

  
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
      
        for (int j = 0; j < n; j++)
        {
            
            printf("#");
        }


    }
}
```

Comment: Learn about using the debugger https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/debugger/getting-started-with-the-debugger-cpp

Comment: Get a sheet of paper and a pen and execute your program yourself (not using the computer). Get the rubber duck and explain what you are executing.   https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rubber_duck_debugging

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because OP could easily (by putting some effort) explain it himself simply by executing this code using his brain, sheet of paper and a pen. But it is easier to write the question. Personally, I would avoid answering similar questions. One can't learn programming without effort.

Comment: I hope you have previously mastered single loops: Because of the `for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)` loop, the computer does `int i = 0;`, then it checks to see if `i < n`. If it isn't, then it goes to the end of the loop. Otherwise it does the stuff inside the loop, does `i++`, and goes back to `i < n` again. This is what a `for` loop does.

Comment: In this program, "the stuff inside the outside loop" is another loop! But that doesn't change how the outside loop works. At all. There are no special rules or hidden gotchas involved. The computer will still do `int i = 0;`, check if `i < n`, do the stuff inside the loop, do `i++`, repeat. It still does n loops, but now every time it loops, it does the whole inside loop which does n loops as well. So the total number of `printf("#");` will be n times n. do you follow?

Comment: @user253751 - FWIW your comment IMO is the best answer.   I can only upclick here.  If it was an answer, I would upclick it there.

Comment: Jason - I appreciate you are a new user.  Welcome!  To really make the best use of this site it would help you tremendously to take time to click the ? button in the upper right corner of this page.  Spend time there learning what and how to ask, and what not to ask, etc.  This question for example is essentially asking for a tutorial, which strictly speaking is off-topic here :)

Answer (score 1):

When you have nested loops, for *each* iteration of the outer loop, the inner loop goes through all of its iterations.

So what happens is not the sum of the iterations of the loops, but the product.  In your case that's 1x1=1, 2x2=4, and 3x3=9.

Answer (score 1):

This is what your code does for any value of n- it counts i up till to N
and then for every i, it counts j till n.
As you may see, for every n, you are again counting N times resulting in n^2 operations. Hence for n=3, you get 9 hashes.

Answer (score 0):

The essence of for loops like the ones you have here is always as follows:
an index starts at 0, some code is executed until that index reaches a value. In case of nested loops like these, the code that gets executed is itself another for loop. If we take n = 3 for example, the sequence looks like this:

```
First iteration of the first loop: i = 0
    First  iteration of the second loop: j = 0
    Second iteration of the second loop: j = 1
    Third  iteration of the second loop: j = 2
Second iteration of the first loop: i = 1
    First  iteration of the second loop: j = 0
    Second iteration of the second loop: j = 1
    Third  iteration of the second loop: j = 2
Third iteration of the first loop: i = 2
    First  iteration of the second loop: j = 0
    Second iteration of the second loop: j = 1
    Third  iteration of the second loop: j = 2
```

Hope this clears things up, and welcome to the wonderful world of programming! :)

Comment: Thanks for kind words. I get it now. I think I got too stressed and my brain fried, even though this is so simple lol

Answer (score 0):

Your confusion is because you're thinking of them as one loop after the other when instead it's one loop inside the other.

```
When `i` is `0`, j is going to do `0`, `1`, `2`
When `i` is `1`, j is going to do `0`, `1`, `2`
When `i` is `2`, j is going to do `0`, `1`, `2`
```

That makes 9.

You're doing the math of 3+3=6 but you've written code that is 3*3=9.

Comment: OMG. Thanks! This makes so much sense (and it's so simple).